# Error XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sitemapprovider

///**This is my Agent.sitemap**

```
<siteMapNode url="default.aspx#" title="Start"  description="Start">

    <siteMapNode url="~/dirCommon/default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home" />

    <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/profile.aspx#" title="Agent" description="Agent">
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/profile.aspx" title="My Profile" description="Agent:My Profile" />
        <siteMapNode url="dirUser/account.aspx" title="My Account" description="Agent:My Account" />
        <!--<siteMapNode url="dirUser/downloads.aspx" title="Downloads" description="Agent:Downloads" />-->
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/default.aspx" title="Calls" description="Calls">
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/CallQueue.aspx" title="Call Queue" description="Agent:Call Queue" />
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/myCalls.aspx" title="My Calls" description="Agent:My Calls" />
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/followupcalls.aspx" title="Follow-Up" description="Agent:Follow-Up" />
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/calls.aspx" title="Call History" description="Agent:Call History" />
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/default3.aspx" title="Environment" description="Environment">
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/facilities.aspx" title="Facilities" description="Agent:Facilities" />
        <!-->
        <siteMapNode url="dirAgent/contacts.aspx" title="Contacts" description="Agent:Contacts" />
        <!-->
    </siteMapNode>

</siteMapNode>
```

//**This Web.sitemap**

```
<siteMapNode url="~/dirCommon/default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home" />
```

//when i run application from iis getting an error "AGENT.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `XmlSiteMapProvider` is configured in the web.config (or code) to use your *Agent.sitemap* instead of the default *~/web.sitemap*. check if that reference and the actual location of the Agent.sitemap are correct!

Comment: <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="DefaultSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
       
        <add siteMapFile="App_Menu/AGENT.sitemap" name="RoleAgentSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

Comment: A) So can you confirm the location "App_Menu/AGENT.sitemap" on your disk? (try NOT using a folder beginning with "APP_") and B) is the file readable for the respective APP_Pool Identity of IIS